# Associate text and time arrays, print and hide values

Tags: javascript

How can I print the `text`array according to `time` array in seconds?
For instance I want that the "tag1" is printed at 2 seconds, "tag2" at 4 seconds, and so on...

http://jsfiddle.net/utG23/

```
var time = [2,4,6,8];
var text = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4'];

var e = document.getElementById("teste");

for (var i=0;i<time.length;i++) {

    e.innerHTML = text[i];
    setTimeout(function(){e.style.display = "none";}, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change text after every `time[i]` seconds period. To make it, use closure:

```
(function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        e.innerHTML = text[i];
    }, 1000 * time[i]);
})(i);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/utG23/1/

Comment: Thank you! And how can I hide the text[i] after 1 second? Because I just want to show the content for 2 seconds, and if time between text = 10, I don't want to see that tag for 10 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

To be perfect...

```
(function(i) {  
    setTimeout(function() {
        e.innerHTML = text[i];
        setTimeout(function(){e.style.display = "none";},3000);
        e.style.display = "block";
    }, 1000 * time[i]);
})(i);
```

It hides the tag after 3 seconds, and then shows it again, when a new one appears...